# A way to fetch Microsoft Graph locations with PnPJs

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, react-typescript, pnp-js, microsoft-exchange

As stated above in the title I am currently facing issues fetching graph `places` with PnPJs, using the @pnp/graph `graphfi` factory interface in SPFx.

I am currently able to fetch data from my events via graphfi as can be seen below:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    graph = graphfi().using(SPFx(props.context));
    getSpecificCalendar();
}, []);

const getSpecificCalendar = async () => {
    await graph.me.events().then((e) => setCalendarEvent(e));
}
```

I have tried to get the `places` property from the `graph` object but to no avail. The only properties present are `me` and `users` but no option for `places`.
Esentially what I want to do is to `graph.places`. The conclusion I have come to is that @pnp/graph does not have any methods to get room data. Any ideas other than what I have tried above would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pnpjs does not have the `/places` endpoint implemented (yet). You could try using the built-in SPFx graph client for now. Something like:

```
const client = await props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3')
const response = await client.api('/places/......').get();
```

Alternatively, you could implement the `/places` endpoint yourself and submit a pull request for pnpjs :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implement endpoint yourself and a pull request for pnpjs"?

Comment: I mean PNPJS library is open source, you can clone it, create the endpoint for `/places` similar to other endpoints, and submit a pull request. Example for `/sites` https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/tree/version-3/packages/graph/sites In short: fix the library and add the missing feature yourself. Then share you work with others.